# Webpack точки выхода

Tags: javascript, webpack

Возможно ли сделать так чтобы у webpack точки входа совпадали с точками выхода без сторонних инструментов? 
Допустим у меня есть несколько файлов:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {

entry: {
        'wheel': './public/WheelOfFortune/js/main.js',
        'abc': './public/abc/js/main.js',
        'cde': './public/cde/js/main.js',
    },
    output: {
        // Как есть сейчас
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
          ... // Здесь я взаимодействую с входящими файлами
        })
    ]
};
```

Т.е. требуется чтобы webpack после всех моих операций заменял файлы из тех же директорий из которых брал

Comment: а зачем это нужно? Или я не совсем понял что имеется ввиду под _возвращал_

Comment: @Grundy, Ну например, webpack поработал со всеми файлами (wheel, abc,cde) и уже обработанные возвращает в папку test и мне вручную их приходится заменять (за место не обработанных). Подправил вопрос)

Comment: давай, чтобы наверняка: есть файл `./public/WheelOfFortune/js/main.js` - ты хочешь, чтобы при сборке именно он заменился на обработанный? или чтобы результат сборки заменился в папке dist, например?

Comment: просто в первом случае операция довольно бессмысленна, а во втором - вроде так по умолчанию и работает